# Animated and getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With `componentWillReceiveProps` being deprecated and the replacement `getDerivedStateFromProps` returning a *final* state, how would i gradually change state over time (i.e. animate something) with the new `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

with `componentWillReceiveProps`, the following works fine:

```
state = {
  itemOpacity: new Animated.Value(0.25)
};

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.items.visible !== nextProps.items.visible) {

    let value = 0;

    if (nextProps.items.visible) {
      value = 1;
    }

    Animated.timing(this.state.itemOpacity, {
      toValue: value,
      duration: 200,
    }).start();
  }
}
```

how would i do something like this with `getDerivedStateFromProps`? or is my animation pattern stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDerivedStateFromProps is called with a newProps and previousState argument. So you can use previousState for the animation:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {

  let value = 0;
  if (nextProps.items.visible) {
    value = 1;
  }

  Animated.timing(prevState.itemOpacity, {
    toValue: value,
    duration: 200,
  }).start();

  return {
    // update state
  }
}
```

Comment: can i just run the animation on the previous state? i assumed that `prevState` is immutable and does not represent the current state.

also, what would i need to return?

Comment: prevState is immutable, but the Animated package does not alter state. In fact, I would advice not to use state for animations since state is only relevant if you explicitly update it through setState()

Comment: thanks, i'll try that later.

but how does `Animated.timing(prevState.itemOpacity ...` not alter state? after that i can see the new value in the state with `this.state.itemOpacity._value`.

Comment: Yes the value gets updated, but it would also get updated if you did not use state. So my previous statement wasn't completely correct. But the animated library does not use state behind the scenes, it just updates the variable you provide it.

Comment: i understand, thank you for clarifying. unfortunately, animating prevState does not actually render an animation.

 your suggestion would be to define an object outside of state/component (`let animations = {opacity: new Animated.Value(0.25) };`) and then run `Animated.timing(animations.opacity ...` on that object?

Comment: Yes, just define a variable inside your constructor, e.g. **this.opacity = new Animated.Value(0.25);** (you don't need let animated = ...) and then reference it in your animation: **Animated.timing(this.opacity ...)**

Comment: how can I return the state after the animation complete in getDerivedStateFromProps?How to return the state in the callback function?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to just not use state for animations (thanks to dentemm for helping out):

```
itemOpacity = new Animated.Value(0.25);

class TestScreen extends Component {

  getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
      let value = 0;

      if (nextProps.items.visible) {
        value = 1;
      }

      Animated.timing(itemOpacity, {
        toValue: value,
        duration: 200,
      }).start();

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked out! I would just suggest to make itemOpacity a member of your component class, for memory management reasons. In the example above you are in fact leaking memory.

Comment: @dentemm This isn't possible, as getDerivedStateFromProps is actually static.